# Check if a character exists in a specific group and create a new column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, match, tidyverse

Thank you in advance for your time reading this post. I have a data.frame  that looks like this

```
time   offspring
 1         1
 1         2
 2         1
 2         5
 3         1
 3         4
```

and I would like to check if the offspring of every time point match the offspring of the last time point. To be more explicit I would like to see if the offspring of the time point 1 and time point 2 are present in the timepoint 3.

When this is the case, then I would like to assign the offspring with the value 1 in a new column and when not with the value 0.4.
For example

```
time   offspring  alpha
 1         1       1
 1         2       0.4
 2         1       1
 2         5      0.4
 3         1       1
 3         4       1
```

Any help and comment are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(offspring) %>%
 mutate(alpha = pmax(0.4, all(1:3 %in% time)))

   time offspring alpha
  <int>     <int> <dbl>
1     1         1   1  
2     1         2   0.4
3     2         1   1  
4     2         5   0.4
5     3         1   1  
6     3         4   0.4
```

If cases that are only present at time period three should be also treated as ones:

```
df %>%
 group_by(offspring) %>%
 mutate(alpha = pmax(0.4, all(1:3 %in% time) | unique(time) == 3))

   time offspring alpha
  <int>     <int> <dbl>
1     1         1   1  
2     1         2   0.4
3     2         1   1  
4     2         5   0.4
5     3         1   1  
6     3         4   1
```

Comment: Both solutions are so neat. Thank you @tmfmnk so much. I would love to know more details about each part of the code "mutate(alpha = pmax(0.4, all(1:3 %in% time) | unique(time) == 3))". I know I am asking too much and please do not feel obliged to do.

Comment: It checks whether all of the values 1, 2 and 3 are present in time or whether there is only one unique value in time that is equal to 3, per groups. If the condition is fulfilled, then it return TRUE, otherwise FALSE. Then, the `pmax()` function returns the maximum value from the pair of values consisting of 0.4 and the result of logical test described above. So, if the condition is TRUE, then the maximum is 1, if FALSE, then the maximum is 0.4.

Comment: Impressive. Very intelligent thinking